# align environment according to *first* character, rather than last

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\begin{align*}
    abcd &= abcd &(abcdefghijk)\\
         &= ab   &(ab)
\end{align*}
```

After the first ampersand the equal signs are aligned. However, after the second ampersand, the closing parentheses ")" are aligned. I'd like the opening parenthesis "(" to be aligned instead. Is there an optional argument like that for align? Am I using the wrong environment? Should I define a new one instead?

Incidentally, how can I avoid having that much white space in between these two?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. `align`:

The `align` environment provides **pairs** or `rl` aligned equations. So, in normal usage the first `&` make the content on the left, be `r`ight aligned and the content on the right be `l`eft aligned. So, you need to insert an additional `&` to make the second `l`eft aligned:

[image]

---

### 2. `alignat`:

If you want to control the spacing between them, I would recommend you use the `alignat` environment.  Similar, to `align`, it also provides pairs of `rl` aligned equations, but unlike `align` the `alignat` does **not** insert additional horizontal spacing in between:

[image]

In the above, I inserted a `\quad` space, without which it looks like:

[image]

### References:

- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    abcd &= abcd &&(abcdefghijk)\\
         &= ab   &&(ab)
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    abcd &= abcd &\quad &(abcdefghijk)\\
         &= ab   &\quad &(ab)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    abcd &= abcd &&(abcdefghijk)\\
         &= ab   &&(ab)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```