# Aligning elements in set

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

How can I create a set with aligned elements? Example:

[image]

I tried using align but it does not align as nicely as in the example.

```
\begin{align*}
    &P = \set{ &A &\rightarrow &a | &b | &c | &d | &e,
    \\& &B &\rightarrow &a | &b | &c}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Your question is not clear. What should be aligned with what?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a
greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange
at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of
our trying to keep everything very concise.
[Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)
is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: What is \set? Please post a minimal example that we can compile our self

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might just want to use a custom `array` for this.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand*\extraBar{\hspace{\tabcolsep}|\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 P =
 \begin{array}[t]{@{} l @{} r@{} >{{}\to}l !{|} l@{}  l@{}}
    \{ & S & aX & bY & \extraBar  c  \\
       & X & bX & bS,                \\
       & Y & bS & cZ,                \\
       & Z & aS & b & \extraBar  c \}
 \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For multiple alignment points, I usually just use the `alignat` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `alignat*=` environment produces as many `rl` pairs as specified in the first paramater and does not insert additional space that the `align` environment does, so you need to insert the space that is desired between the alignment points.
- The double `&&` ensure that the subsequent columns are also left aligned.

### References:

- There is a brief discussion on the difference between `align` and `alignat` at [align environment according to *first* character, rather than last](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82273/align-environment-according-to-first-character-rather-than-last).
- The discussion at [What is the mandatory argument of alignedat for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96124/what-is-the-mandatory-argument-of-alignedat-for) also applies to the mandatory parameter to for `alignat`.
- [Why is \mid so called?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52901/why-is-mid-so-called)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    P = \{ && S &\to aX && \mid bY && \mid c  \\
           && X &\to bX && \mid bS,                \\
           && Y &\to bS && \mid cZ,                \\
           && Z &\to aS && \mid b  && \mid c \}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mid` is a symbol defined in plain tex as (i believe) a binary operator.  so the name was assigned by knuth.  my guess is that is so named because it comes in the middle of a math expression, as opposed to the similarly shaped verts that are used as delimiters.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\mid` is defined as a relation, not a binary operator, though I have seen `|` it used as a binary operator.

Comment: @Dan -- thanks for the correction of the class.  (i'm not able to check easily; more than 6500 miles from my reference library with a *very* tenuous internet connection.)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be that horizontal spacing is enormously big. Therefore I have chosen some values, giving a similar result, in my opinion. There is some manual work, but no additional packages are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l@{\kern1pt}l@{\kern4pt|\kern4pt}l@{\kern4pt|\kern4pt}l}
P=\{&S\to{aX}  & bY  & c,\\
& X\to{bX}  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\kern-\arraycolsep bS, } \\
& Y\to{bS}  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\kern-\arraycolsep cZ, }\\
& Z\to{aS}  & b   &  c\}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]